# Bash JSON: Add Var

Tags: json, bash, curl

I'm trying to use `curl` command to perform a POST request. The format of the content is the message I am POSTing is JSON. In the example below, I don’t get how to add the `$*` part, which should be all parameters you add when you start the `.sh` file.

```
curl -X POST --data-urlencode 'payload={"channel": "#serverstatus", "username": "BananaStatus", "text": "${*}", "icon_emoji": ":banana:"}' https://hooks.slack.com/services/
```

When I run that, I just receive the `${*}` as text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bash don't expand variables between ' ' (single quotes)

you have to use double quote (" ")

try:

```
'...any text..'"${*}"'...other text..'
```

it gives whith your example:

```
curl -X POST --data-urlencode 'payload={"channel": "#serverstatus", "username": "BananaStatus", "text": "'"${*}"'", "icon_emoji": ":banana:"}' https://hooks.slack.com/services/
```

Answer (score 1):

When using variables in the middle of strings you should use double quotes.

So, use:

```
"payload={\"channel\": \"#serverstatus\", \"username\": \"BananaStatus\", \"text\": \"${*}\", \"icon_emoji\": \":banana:\"}"
```

Instead of:

```
'payload={"channel": "#serverstatus", "username": "BananaStatus", "text": "${*}", "icon_emoji": ":banana:"}'
```